# How to POST a new issue comment to github api?

Tags: node.js, github-api

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have a repo where I test things and everything should be pretty straight forward, but.
I am using node.js, but that is not much relevant in this problem:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/repos/capaj/gitup/issues/1/comments',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'bot'},
    json: {
        "body": 'my uber comment'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); 
    } else {
        //I always get 404
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's the code that [authenticates you with the server](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)?

Comment: @Jordan it is really beautiful that API, but sometimes the documentation is very very lacking.  I was trying to do it without any authentication. Of course it is not going to work-but I just did not realize. Ok, so only thing github needs is my token right?

Comment: Have you considered just using the [GitHub module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github)?